# How to check running UDP Client connection status at UDP server

Tags: c#, udp

In udp socket communication,**Client** is continuously receiving data from **server**.if **server** is closed,how **client** can knows that **server** is closed or not

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protcol. There is no concept of 'client is closed'.

Comment: What do you mean by "connection" in this case?

Comment: Implement connection management layer at your application layer. Basically, try to mimic TCP. Also, are you sure that you need UDP? Most of the time you want to use TCP unless you need fast protocol and you don't care about data-loss.

Comment: if UDP client connection is lost while receiving data from UDP Client, i need to notify that there is no client

Comment: There is no way you could do this. In UDP, once a packet is sent the sender does not care if the client receives it or not. So it does not matter if a client is closed mid-transmission.